# Invoke ScriptBlocks from C# with Live-Output

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to write a class-type-definition inside a PowerShell module. This one contains list which holds scriptblocks and some other variables. As well it has a function to invoke all the scriptblocks in its list available.

To invoke a scriptblock I've tried several approaches and ended at the easiest one, e.g.:

```
Powershell psinstance = PowerShell.Create()
psinstance.AddScript("bla bla bla")
psinstance.Invoke()
```

This works fine so far, but I have a delicate detail I want to have.

This invocation just returns the output after it has been completely finished.

For a specific example, let's use another scriptblock, which describes this problem the best. First from PowerShell directly:

```
$a = { ping 127.0.0.1 }
```

if you run this one with

```
& $a
```

or

```
Invoke-Expression $a
```

you'll get a line by line output directly. So the first ping sends you'll receive the first line, the second ping sends, you'll receive the second line, and so on.

But if you do a

```
$a.Invoke()
```

you'll only get the full results after 4 pings have been send, after 4 seconds at all. Or if you would use a t-argument, it would run for ever without an output at all.

The same 'issue' I get, if I invoke this scriptblock through the C# code

But I want the behavior I would get when using the call operator or `Invoke-Expression` from inside PowerShell.

**How do I receive the live output to my console?**

I would also be happy, if I knew what the & operator (or `Invoke-Expression`) is doing exactly in the .Net background.

But maybe it's just something I cannot see ATM. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

the invoke command allows to add a parameter for the output (IList). if you use an observablecollection as output parameter and you attach to the CollectionChanged event then you can write the output to your console:

```
var psinstance = System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Create();
psinstance.AddScript("ping 127.0.0.1");

var output = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<string>();
output.CollectionChanged += (object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) =>
{
    foreach(var item in e.NewItems)
        Console.WriteLine(item);
};
psinstance.Invoke(null, output);
```

Comment: I tried this in a demo project and it worked very well. I will include it in my main project where I will remove the usage of the Process class. Until now I think that this one should be marked as the answer to the question